# .NET Programming tasks that need Local Admin rights

Tags: .net, permissions

At our company all the developers have local admin rights.  But now one of my newer coworkers has to justify needing local admin rights.

So he asked me what we do that requires local admin rights.

Problem is, I have the rights, so I don't know what I would not be able to do without them.

We develop stuff like ASP.NET, WCF Services, WPF apps, SSIS packages, General SQL Server Development.  We also do some legacy Client Server Delphi stuff (Delphi 5 and Delphi 6).

Does any one know **specific** tasks that would not be possible without Local Admin rights?

Comment: See also: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/62207/windows-permissions-for-developers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't run/debug using the full fledged IIS w/o local admin rights.

You can't copy files into protected directories. May or may not be important.

Plus hundreds of other minor PITA things that we as developers do every day.

Comment: Yeah, it is the hundereds of PITA things that I am hoping to enumerate.  But the debug with IIS is a solid one.  Thanks.

Comment: You _can_ use IIS Express w/o local admin though.

Comment: @BNL not on a "low" port, you can't

Answer (score 7):

Hundreds of *little* hurdles, each themselves solvable via a call to whoever runs the network, but each that adds delays and takes you out of "the zone". Thinking aloud:

- installing random tools to **find out** if they solve the problem (our job is creative, not scripted)
- changing "hosts" regularly to target individual nodes behind a cluster
- developing anything that acts as a network server - or often as a client
- installing ad-hoc certs
- looking through event logs

You could say: do it on a VM, but IDEs really need as much power as you can give then, and you need to be admin on the vm anyway

Answer (score 2):

Here is an official list of *User Permissions and Visual Studio* from MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj662724.aspx

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/user-permissions-and-visual-studio?view=vs-2022 more recent version of that page :-)

Answer (score 1):

Obscure, but for some reason you can't run WatiN tests through MSTest unless you are running as administrator.

But of course, running WatiN through NUnit works fine, which just another testament to the awfulness of MSTest.

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET you won't be able to create Virtual Directories in IIS (by default VS won't load the Web or WCF projects). You might be able to get away with Cassini / Web Development Server.

In WCF, you won't be able to netsh to open up ports and URIs to listen to.

In SQL you won't have the default LocalAdmin = System Admin mapping, so additional permissions will be needed before you can run SQL profiler or create new databases.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run some of the performance/profiling  tools such as the concurrency visualizer unless VS is run as Administrator.